# Merchant Frequency with Repeat Users Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a consumer dataset which contains transactions made by the consumer. Each consumer has made more than one person thus the data is repeat consumers. I want to loop through the dataset and for each consumer and find the number of different merchants they transacted through and add that info as a new column.
Below is how the current dataset looks like.

| Customer ID | Merchant |
| --- | --- |
| A | USPS |
| B | Apple |
| A | USPS |
| B | Apple |
| B | USPS |
| C | Microsoft |

This is how i want it to be:

| Customer ID | Merchant | Merchants Visited |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | USPS | 1 |
| B | Apple | 2 |
| A | USPS | 1 |
| B | Apple | 2 |
| B | USPS | 2 |
| C | Microsoft | 1 |

NOTE:

I tried the code below and it works on small dataset but does not work on my data set which has about 199,000 rows.

merchant_number = list(range(len(repeat_consumer)))
for i in range(len(repeat_consumer)):
merchant_number[i] = repeat_consumer[repeat_consumer['Consumer ID']==repeat_consumer['Consumer ID'][i]].Merchant.nunique()

repeat_consumer['Merchants Visited'] = merchant_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Merchants Visited"] = df.groupby("Customer ID")["Merchant"].transform(
    "nunique"
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Customer ID   Merchant  Merchants Visited
0           A       USPS                  1
1           B      Apple                  2
2           A       USPS                  1
3           B      Apple                  2
4           B       USPS                  2
5           C  Microsoft                  1
```